# Is SharePoint injecting a second command menu bar?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, json-formatting, spfx-extensions

I've inherited the SPFx components of a SharePoint solution that has a custom command set that replaces the OOB command menu bar items.The OOB menu items are removed by looping over `"ms-OverflowSet-item"`s with `setInterval` to set their display.

`el.style.display = "none";`

Up until recently, this worked fine but now the OOB command bar gets added *again* after the max interval has been reached and the `Promise` returned.

It seems clear that it is an additional command bar because if I extend the interval, set breakpoints on the display updates, I can see the elements are already hidden, yet they're back on the screen along with my custom commands.

I've tried a bunch of hacky stuff including removing all the locations where we set the display of the command bar back to `""` but nothing works; I can only assume something changed in SharePoint to cause this new behavior.

Any ideas on the cause or a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM manipulations using HTML element ID/classes are not recommended by Microsoft as some of your customizations may break if Microsoft changes HTML element id/classes in new release updates.

---

This week Microsoft introduced a new feature in SharePoint JSON formatting using which you can **hide**/customize the command bar options using view formatting.

So, you don't have to use any custom CSS to hide the command bar options from SPFx.

**Example**: Below example hides "New" command & customizes display of "Edit in grid view" command:

```
{
  "commandBarProps" : {
    "commands": [
      {
        "key": "new",
        "hide": true
      },
      {
        "key": "editInGridView",
        "text": "Quick edit",
        "iconName": "EditTable",
        "primary": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Check this documentation for more information about the syntax & command keys you can target in JSON formatting: [Command bar customization syntax reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-commandbar-formatting)

Comment: Yeah, I've known our approach wasn't recommended and unreliable but kicking the can down the road was the easiest thing to do for the original authors. I'm not 100% sure where I need to put that json but I also need to show or hide based on a combination of roles and group permissions; can these props be updated dynamically? If so, do you have a reference for that?

Comment: You need to put above code in **Format current view** option for a list view. Check more info at: [View formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting). **No**, you cannot use roles and group permissions in JSON formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the update; looks like it's not a viable option due to the inability to use it based on roles and groups. But I also don't get that option in the drop down for the list in question; I can see more options for a split second before they're hidden. Not sure what that's about but it doesn't matter anyway I guess. Oh, well; thanks for the help.